# Need to sandbox application that compiles C++ modules from untrusted sources online

Tags: c++, compilation, sandbox

I’m developing a C++ application where I want to compile C++ modules from potentially untrusted sources online, and have them operate on a specific bank of data within a single process. I’d like to sandbox these somehow.  This is obviously a complex issue, but hoping to discover if there’s any potential approach or tool/library I haven’t yet thought of. The app will run on Windows & OSX at minimum, and (hopefully) Linux, iOS, Android.

My app would locally compile the C++ modules it downloads, and dynamically link the object code to a process in the app (not necessarily the “main” app process). The C++ modules would only have access to my API via the headers I provide, however the API (and any dependent libraries) need to be linked into the same process. The API’s dependent libraries are compute-based only, such as native SIMD-based math and possibly memory allocation. I don’t expect they will need to call any network, disk, or any other OS functionality, for that matter – except for needing to communicate their input data and computed results to the main process (maybe over shared memory ?)

I don’t care if the sandboxed process’ memory is corrupted or hollowed, as long as it’s contained in that process. I also want to avoid having any system API call addresses linked into in the process memory space, to prevent compromised code from finding them.

I’ve done a review of the basic security issues (stack crashes, return oriented programming hacks, etc.). Also looked at some related projects:

1. I see Google has a sandbox subproject within the Chromium repo which might be useful, but unsure of it’s utility in my case.
2. Windows Sandbox is a Microsoft tool for Windows only, and isn’t available on some versions anyway. Moreover. there are big performance issues with using it. The app runs in real time, with frame rate requirements similar to a video game.
3. considered compiling to WebAssembly, but at the moment it seems too immature (no SIMD, hard to debug, and potentially vulnerable to hacks in the wrapping host or browser.)
4. I thought there might be some kind of wrapper library already out there to intercept all OS calls and allow custom configuration of what calls get passed through (in my case, anything except what’s needed for the inter-process communication would be denied)

Any other ideas, architectural suggestions, or promising open source projects on the horizon for this ?

Thanks,
C

Comment: An update: to clarify, any memory allocation the process needs would be hooked with my own heap allocator to avoid having to call the OS.

Comment: My company uses VMware to run images as sandboxes (within a VM), which can relatively easily be managed and restored in an automated fashion, and when needed in a manual fashion.

Comment: update: Instead of compiling C++, considered running the code as LUA scripts, or some other reasonably fast language, but thought I'd just be adding that language's own runtime vulnerabilities into the mix on top of my basic API.

Answer (score 1):

Compiling untrusted source code and linking to your app sounds really unsafe. If I understand your problem correctly, you need to "provide safe runtime environment for single threaded user code with only access to your API", then in my opinion its better to use runtime interpreter instead. It will provide you more control and sandbox capabilities, safe API calls and users code exceptions handling.

If you have doubts about interpreters performance, its a good trade of to safety, flexibilty and control. Vast of interpreters compile source code to bytecode and runs realy fast. Also you can reach better performance by providing fast API to script.

In my Java enterprise projects I use built-in Rhino JavaScript interpreter to run user scripts and provide API to reach flexibility, required performance and control. This scripts can call nothing but my API. Its safe, flexible and absolutely controllable.

I found these C/C++ (C like syntax) interpreter libraries:

1. JavaScript (ECMA)
   https://v8.dev/
2. Lua
   http://acamara.es/blog/2012/08/running-a-lua-5-2-script-from-c/
3. C++ interpreter
   https://github.com/root-project/cling

Comment: (a) Cling looks interesting, thanks - though probably no way prevent invalid pointer access. (b) You're right, interpreted code can offer decent performance. There are still cases where C/C++ is desirable, however - hence projects like Chromium Sandbox, etc.